# Oracle flashback: Is there a way to get the REDO SQL queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, undo-redo, flashback

Within the **oracle database 11g** the table `FLASHBACK_TRANSACTION_QUERY` provides the `UNDO_SQL` column which SQL reverses the modification done by a specific previously executed query.

However, I need the `REDO_SQL` (the original `SQL` which has been executed) instead.
Is there a way (using SQLs) to extract `REDO_SQL` information from the **oracle flashback** area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_flashback.htm), Oracle flashback features focused on data rather than SQL statements. Therefore you can't discover statements from flashback data.

Instead, you can enable **AUDIT** feature in database settings ([AUDIT_TRAIL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams017.htm#REFRN10006) parameter), then manage auditing settings with `AUDIT` statement as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_4007.htm#i2116021).

Logged statements can be accessed with [`DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_3073.htm) or `USER_AUDIT_TRAIL` views.

Another way to reach same target is to use [`DBMS_FGA`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_fga.htm) package to tune up audit policies and then refer [`DBA_FGA_AUDIT_TRAIL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_2104.htm) or [`V$XML_AUDIT_TRAIL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2182.htm) for list of executed statements. This option involves [Fine Grained Auditing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/security/index-083815.html) feature and available only for Enterprise version of Oracle Database.

**Update**

Sorry for initial mistake, real name of view to examine audit records is `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL` (corrected above).

This view can be joined on `TRANSACTIONID` field with the field `XID` of `FLASHBACK_TRANSACTION_QUERY` view to get corresponding flashback records.

Besides Oracle documentation there are a number of good [articles on Oracle-Base site](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/auditing-10gr2.php) about auditing.

Comment: Is it possible to examine commited statements only (using the oracle AUDIT feature)?

Comment: @MRalwasser Sorry about mistake, please look at updated answer. But one limitation remains: you can't determine exact statement inside transaction which caused changes in the data.